# Why will this universal selector property not be overwritten

Tags: css

Suppose I have some table in HTML and apply this:

```
* { font-family: Verdana }
table { font-family: Arial }
```

The font-family remains Verdana, although I told it explicitly to change it to Arial. If I add another property, say, `background-color: blue`, then the style gets applied. I think there's something going on with inheritance here I don't get. I understand that the asterisk selects all elements, but `table` also applies the style to its child elements and its precedence should be higher than the asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` rule also applies to TD, TR, TBODY, THEAD, TFOOT and TH because you overrode the default of `inherit`.

I recommend setting the font on the `html` or `body` elements instead of ever using `*`.

You can also add `td` to the `table` rule.

Comment: What do you mean by "overrode the default of inherit"?